# Build Refreshable Query From Multiple Connections AS400 IBMi

Tags: excel, vba, ibm-midrange

My attempt was to create a simple PivotTable on the fly from multiple tables from an AS400 IBMi. That was achieved, but the PivotTable is not "refreshable".

So I started looking at posts about programmatically creating connections and came up with the example below that is refreshable, but to only one table:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections.AddFromFile "N:\apps\excel\connections\PRD IS.odc"
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("PRD IS").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM ""PRD"".""Y2K"".""IS""")
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .Connection = "ODBC;DSN=s11111111;"
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .SavePassword = False
    .SourceConnectionFile = "N:\apps\excel\connections\PRD IS.odc"
    .SourceDataFile = ""
    .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
    .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("PRD IS")
    .Name = "PRD IS"
End With

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("PRD IS"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=ActiveCell, TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

Is it possible to use two connections, combine them, and create the final result that is refreshable?

The second connection would be:

```
      ActiveWorkbook.Connections.AddFromFile "N:\apps\excel\connections\PRD PM.odc"
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("PRD PM").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM ""PRD"".""Y2K"".""PM""")
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .Connection = "ODBC;DSN=s111111111;"
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .SavePassword = False
    .SourceConnectionFile = "N:\apps\excel\connections\PRD PM.odc"
    .SourceDataFile = ""
    .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
    .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("PRD PM")
    .Name = "PRD PM"
End With
```

Currently working code:

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()
'Declare variables
Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim Param As ADODB.Parameter
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set Cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'Open Connection'
Conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=s11111111;"
Conn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
Set Cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn

Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ISWH as WH,ISPART as Part,PMDESC as Description,ISCF01 As AC, PMPCLS As PC, PMPLIN As PL" & _
" FROM Y2K.IS LEFT JOIN Y2K.PM ON Y2K.IS.ISPART = Y2K.PM.PMPART" & _
" WHERE(ISWH) in ('XX')" & _
" AND (ISCF01) not in ('B','D')" & _
" AND (PMPLIN) in ('YY')" & _
" AND (PMPCLS) like ('Z%')"

Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Open Recordset'
Set rs.Source = Cmd
rs.Open

'Create a PivotTable cache and report.
Set objPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlExternal)
Set objPivotCache.Recordset = rs
objPivotCache.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=ActiveCell, TableName:="PivotTable1"

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    .SmallGrid = False
    With .PivotFields("WH")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Part")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("PL")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("PC")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 1
    End With
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! What kind of VBA stuff is that. I've never seen that before. Cool!

Comment: lol... you at least broke up my day.

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't create the combination of the queries on the server?

Comment: yes....I do not have that ability/access.... at best I would have to bring them in to MS Access and create it.

Comment: An alternative would be to write the recordset to a worksheet within the workbook, then base the pivot table off the local worksheet data.

Comment: @Fink I was able to figure it out.  I will post the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured this out.  Instead of adding connections that already existed, I added a new one and defined it.

```
"Test" is the name of the connection
"x" is the description
"Conn" is the connection string
"Cmdarray" is the sql

Sub CreatePivotTable()
Dim Cmdarray
Dim Conn

Cmdarray = Array("SELECT ISWH as WH, ISPART as Part,PMDESC as Description, ISCF01 as AC FROM ""PRD"".""Y2K"".""IS"" LEFT JOIN ""PRD"".""Y2K"".""PM"" ON ""PRD"".""Y2K"".""IS"".ISPART = ""PRD"".""Y2K"".""PM"".PMPART WHERE (ISWH) IN ('XX')")

Conn = "ODBC;DSN=s111111111;"

ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add "Test", "x", Conn, Cmdarray

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Test"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=ActiveCell, TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
End Sub
```